# Realtek ALC295, HP Spectre laptop - headphones play audio in Windows but don't play audio in Linux

Tags: arch-linux, audio, pulseaudio, alsa

[I have this laptop - HP Spectre x360 13-w023dx](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Spectre-x360-Convertible-PC-series/12499178/model/13443279/document/c05348992/).

Basically my headphones work in Windows but they don't work in Linux (specifically Arch Linux). In Linux, my headphones are detected (i.e. the system volume changes when I connect my headphones) but I can't seem to get any audio to play out at all.

I have tried audio when booting from an Ubuntu Live CD and it still doesn't work.

I've tried `hdajackretask` and following [this](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Audio/HP-Omen-with-ALC295-Audio-Problems-under-Linux/td-p/7029059), but all it does is play audio through the speakers like nothing was connected to the headphone jack at all.

Also, playing audio via a USB-C audio interface only works in Windows, a similar problem happens when playing in Linux.

Here is the output of `pactl list sinks` when the headphones are connected, if it helps:

```
Sink #0
        State: SUSPENDED
        Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
        Description: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
        Driver: module-alsa-card.c
        Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
        Channel Map: front-left,front-right
        Owner Module: 6
        Mute: no
        Volume: front-left: 16381 /  25% / -36.13 dB,   front-right: 16381 /  25% / -36.13 dB
                balance 0.00
        Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
        Monitor Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor
        Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
        Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
        Properties:
                alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
                device.api = "alsa"
                device.class = "sound"
                alsa.class = "generic"
                alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
                alsa.name = "ALC295 Analog"
                alsa.id = "ALC295 Analog"
                alsa.subdevice = "0"
                alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
                alsa.device = "0"
                alsa.card = "0"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xdc228000 irq 134"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "8086"
                device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
                device.product.id = "9d71"
                device.product.name = "Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio"
                device.form_factor = "internal"
                device.string = "front:0"
                device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
                device.buffering.fragment_size = "176400"
                device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
                device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
                device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
                device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
                alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC295"
                alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0295,103c827e,00100002 HDA:8086280b,80860101,00100000"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        Ports:
                analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority: 10000, not available)
                analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority: 9000, available)
        Active Port: analog-output-headphones
        Formats:
                pcm
```

Any help to get my headphones to work (and also USB-C audio) would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

there is an audio codec 'fixup' for this laptop
use this command in terminal

```
echo 'options snd-hda-intel model=alc295-hp-x360' | sudo tee --append /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

this creates a file alsa-base.conf (file name can be anything, but must end in '.conf' in /etc/modprobe.d/ folder)

reboot to load laptop model configuration for audio driver

Comment: I saw this fix online and I tried it but it didn't work. Still no audio through headphones.

Comment: @etnguyen03: Look through `dmesg` after to boot to verify that your kernel is new enough to recognize the model option and apply the fix. If it doesn't, switch to a newer kernel.

Comment: @dirkt `dmesg | grep hda` doesn't mention anything about the `alc295-hp-x360` fix, all that I see is [here](https://pastebin.com/1fp4WnTS).

Comment: Then I'd assume it's not new enough.